Redirecting to a page when rate limit has been reached not working in ASP.NET Core
I am implementing ASP.NET Core rate limiting, per fixed window:
builder.Services.AddRateLimiter(options =>
        {
            options.GlobalLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(httpContext =>
            {
                var remoteIpAddress = httpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                var localIpAddress = httpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;
                var partitionKey = $"{remoteIpAddress} {localIpAddress}";

                return RateLimitPartition.GetFixedWindowLimiter(partitionKey, options => new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions
                {
                    AutoReplenishment = true,
                    PermitLimit = 10,
                    QueueLimit = 0,
                    Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst
                });
            });

            options.OnRejected = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                if (context.Lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.RetryAfter = ((int)retryAfter.TotalSeconds).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                }
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/RateLimitExceeded", false);
            };
        });

As you can see, I want to redirect to some URL, in this case, it's a Razor page, and, of course, I don't want it to be involved in the rate limiting process, so I add a [DisableRateLimiting] attribute to the model:
[DisableRateLimiting]
public class RateLimitExceededModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet() { }
}

However, try as I might, I can't get this too work, meaning, when the limit is reached, I always get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error, which means I somehow entered a redirect loop.
How can I make this work, that is, redirect to a custom page that is exempt from rate limiting?

There's nothing wrong with the codes you provided,notice the order of the middlwares,app.UseRateLimiter();should be placed after Routing middlware.
I tried to reproduce the issue with your codes.If the middlewares are in the correct order,it works well:

but if the middlewares are not in correct order:


Thanks, @Ruikai Feng! It seems that my MapRazorPages was on the wrong place!
